# I can not login with sa user with entity framework in .net core web api project 6.0. I am able to login on with sa user on sql server management

Tags: entity-framework, authentication, sa

I have a .net core 6.0 web api project. I am using entity framework code first.
I am trying to login with sa user. I set a password for sa user on sql server management and I am able to login with sa user and password on sql server managment. But I set the same username(sa) and password I am not able to login. So the database is not create. I have received a login failed message.

**my appsettings.json**

```
{"Logging": {"LogLevel": {"Default": "Information","Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"}},"AllowedHosts": "*","ConnectionStrings": {"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Database=userdddd;Persist Security Info=True;User Id=SA;Password=YXZakamoz21?-*54;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=10;"}}
```

**My userDbcontex**

```
namespace ffff.Userwebservice.DbContex{public class UserDbContext : DbContext{public UserDbContext(DbContextOptions<UserDbContext> options) : base(options){}
```

```
    DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    DbSet<AccessGrants> AccessGrants { get; set; }
}
```

```
}
```

**My program.cs**

```
using ffff.Userwebservice.Repository;using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

```
// Add services to the container.
```

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbucklebuilder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options =>options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), sqlOptions =>{sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 5,maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),errorNumbersToAdd: null);}).EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
```

```
var app = builder.Build();
```

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()){app.UseSwagger();app.UseSwaggerUI();}
```

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

```
//app.UseAuthorization();
```

```
app.MapControllers();
```

```
app.Run();
```

I tryed many type of the connection. But I could not logined with entity framework.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsckS.png)

Comment: Please copy/paste the EXACT ERROR MESSAGE.  And please confirm your app is co-located with your DB - that both are running on localhost.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks a lot for answer. Run Add-Migration and Update-Database The database is created. The problem is solved.

Comment: Q: So it sounds like you're using Entity Framework, you're doing "code first" ... and, since you never did a migration, your app was trying to connect to a database that didn't exist yet.  Whoops.  Glad you got it resolved.  Again: going forward, please remember to include the EXACT ERROR MESSAGE in your question!